# What is the highest single-target damage possible in a nova round by a solo character at level 7?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization

Assuming the following;

- No magic items
- No pre-combat preparation outside of very-long duration buffs
- No aid by party members
- The character starts within movement range of the target
- The target has 16 AC and +2 to all saves except Constitution and Strength, which are +5
- The target is a humanoid, with no resistances or immunities
- The target is Medium size
- The target is not Surprised, but has not yet acted
- The character uses 27 point point buy as a stat generation method
- The target has no special abilities (counterspell, legendary resistances etc) that are relevant on other people's turns, other than the ability to opportunity attack.

Which build can do the most damage in a single round to a single target at level 7?  Repeatability or utility are not requirements - just which combination of races/classes/choices etc does the absolute most damage in a single round.

Comment: As some of the answer ignore to hit chances, but you are giving Saves and AC here, is it correct to assume you are looking for expected damage inlcuding the effect of missing and the target making saves, or are you looking for possible maximum damage if all the rolls go the right way?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin an answer presenting the maximum possible damage and the expected damage would likely be superior to an answer presenting only the maximum possible damage

Comment: Can you assume the target has no other abilities? If you want an answer with max expected damage, spell attack odds would be decreased if the target had something like counter spell.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Wild Magic Sorcerer: 1152

To be clear, this isn't gonna be anywhere near likely or reliable, but sure a lot.

We start by using our bonus action to burn all our sorcery points into a single, 5th level slot (note that Font of Magic has no limit against doing so). None of the metamagics would actually help here anyway.

Now, with our action, we'll be casting a spell that has us make an attack roll (order doesn't matter). On that, we use Tides of Chaos. The advantage isn't important, we just want the automatic and importantly repeatable wild magic surge†. This in addition to the one-per-turn we need to roll for.

For most of these surges, we want to  roll 81-82 on the wild magic table (see below for the other results). With that result, we cast another spell, repeating the loop until we've run out of spell slots.

If, on the one-per-turn surge, we roll 59-60, we regain our lowest expended spell slot, letting us repeat the above loop an additional time for a 5th level slot (assuming we started with that).

If you're assuming a crit and max damage, the most efficient single target spells for us are *chromatic orb* for 1st level slots and *scorching ray* for everything above that.

That deals a nice 1104 damage with all our spell slots, and with one final surge with which we'll *fireball* ourselves for another 48, bringing us to a total of 1152. If, instead, you're feeling a bit frail, you can go with the 2nd most damage efficient option of *magic missile* (09-10; upcast to 5th) for 35 and a total of 1139.

---

†: Wild magic surges, in addition to a fairly clunky rules wording and errata, has a built in DM-opt in. We're here assuming the DM always says yes, which is probably a much more solid assumption that always rolling exactly what we want.

Comment: Why does Fireball deal 48 to both people? I don't see anything in the question stopping you from moving 25 feet away, Fireballing ad absurdum, and then moving 5 feet back for the final Surge fireball.

Comment: @Phoenices Because the *fireball* is centered on you. You can't avoid hitting yourself, but can include the desired target if you're close enough

Comment: I upvoted but for clarification, is there some errata that makes the wild magic surge of Tides of Chaos mandatory? My PHB still has the language "*Any time before you regain the use of this feature, the DM can have you roll on the Wild Magic Surge table*", so wouldn't that mean it's up to the DM? (Real question, as one of my players just made a Wild Magic Sorcerer, and I told him, its up to the DM).

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Yes, and thank you for reminding me. There's a limit on the normal roll for to one per turn, which breaks the extended method and the infinite loop (without an at-will leveled sorcerer spell). Made a footnote about technically needing DM opt-in, though honestly I'd expect luck to run out far way before a DM stops the loop (but that's the realistic scenario, which this Q&A is not).

Comment: Does a 5th-level slot you manufactured yourself count as "expended", for regaining as your lowest-level expended slot via a surge?  I guess if you haven't expended any of the spell slots you started with, then yeah.  But how would regaining it let you do anything with it on the same turn?  If it's at the end of dumping all your spell slots, your lowest level expended slot would be 1st.  So you mean if you roll that, you can try to start the nova loop again next turn, after having cast a 5th-level spell and nothing else this turn?

Comment: Weird, unlikely, vaguely horrifying, and technically correct.  The best kind of correct.  Bravo.

Comment: @PeterCordes Typo, yes. As for the 5th level slot: I see nothing in Font of Magic that indicates the slot disappears when used, it just usually doesn't matter. And yes, the presumption is that you start with that 5th level slot, get two surges of casting (one-per-turn and ToC) for a slot regain and additional action.

Comment: There is an errata on Flexible Casting that "Any spell slot you create with this feature vanishes when you finish a long rest." Based on that, as long as you haven't used any of your 1st-4th level spell slots (which as a Sorcerer 7, you have enough points to make the 5th level slot without converting existing slots to points), then I agree that this means 59-60 restores the 5th level slot.

Answer (score 11):

### Half-Orc Paladin 5 / Fighter 2 with GWM can deal 449 damage in a single round

From 5 levels in Paladin you have two level 2 spellslots and four level 1 spellslots. Attacking and critting with a greataxe (1d12), you deal

- 36+3 damage from the greataxe (half-orc crit is 3d12)
- 32 or 48 damage from smite depending on spellslot
- +10 from GWM

So that's a total of 81 or 97 damage per attack. Due to extra attack and GWM we can attack 3 times in one turn which comes out to (using our highest spellslots first) 97+97+81 = 275. We then action surge and do it all again, this time without the GMW extra attack and with only level 1 spellslots for 81×2 = 162. Then, just to cap it off, we use the Superior Technique fighting style in one of our attacks to add a superiorty die to our damage which crits for +12. This comes out to a total of 449 damage.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Yes, it is. "*You learn one maneuver of your choice from among
those available to the Battle Master archetype* (...)"